# Can Roslyn compile C# to CIL

Tags: c#, roslyn

Can the Roslyn C# compiler be used to compile C# to CIL human readable code?  Like the examples shown here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language

I know it can produce bytecode in EXE/DLL form, but I'm interested in the CIL code.

Either from the command line or API.

I know a disassembler could be used on the bytecode files but I would prefer a more direct approach.

Thanks.

Comment: .Net and .net core need an clr. Therefore they need an il. When you build an dll or exe the compiler turns your code into msil (Microsoft Intermediate Language). You can view this with tools like `IL DASM`.

Comment: why not using ILdasm ?

Comment: I didn't want to use a disassembler -  just seems too complex - I thought the compiler would have the MSIL somewhere internally that I wanted direct access to

Comment: No, it does not maintain IL in any intermediate form. Bytecode is emitted directly by the `ILBuilder` class. The simplest solution *is* to disassemble the code after it's been generated.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Do you want to post that as an asnwer?

Comment: Here is an excerpt from an [interview](https://www.i-programmer.info/professional-programmer/i-programmer/7154-c-guru-an-interview-with-eric-lippert.html?start=1) with Eric Lippert: _Roslyn is a class library usable from C#, VB or other managed languages.Its purpose is to enable analysis of C# and VB code. So typical tasks you could perform with Roslyn would be things like:

"Find all usages of a particular method in this source code"
"Take this source code and give me the lexical and grammatical analysis"
"Tell me all the places this variable is written to inside this block"_

Answer (score 3):

Simply call ildasm.exe as your post-build step. Solutions should be composable steps instead of one monolithic monstrosity.

Answer (score 3):

[SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/) can translate C#, Visual Basic, or F# on-the-fly to a number of formats, one of which is CIL.

It does so using Roslyn from the Roslyn repo and you can select which version you want it to use.

It's not an extension/command line tool/API, but it's likely to be very useful for anyone else trying to view CIL easily.

Answer (score 1):

C# is automatically compiled to CIL. That is the target platform. (*Not sure about .NET Native/UWP).

Since it seems to me, that your goal is to show the generated CIL code, take a look at [Msiler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=segrived.Msiler):

[image]

If you by chance use Resharper, [there is an IL-Viewer included](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2017/01/19/exploring-intermediate-language-il-with-resharper-and-dotpeek/).